# How to stop audit I find bad from being reused?

Tags: support, review-audits

Just failed my first review audit. Not really too big a deal, I guess; I'm a little upset, especially since it seems the "right" answer (flag a laconic answer as NAA and then delete it!) wasn't actually correct, but I'm not banned, and I passed several audits already so I know I am in fact paying attention as a general rule.

The only reason I'm bothering anyone else about this is in case this (seemingly) bad audit will be reused for others in the future, because if so, obviously, weeding it out right now is the thing to do. And since I couldn't find anything on the subject that said straight out whether this sort of reuse happens, I figured I'd post this.

Comment: There are ways to short-circuit such audits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you mean characteristics audits share that can tip off the reviewer to be more careful? Because yes, but I'd prefer to avoid cheating my way past, even past bad audits. It's also not readily apparent whether an audit will be correct or not, and an audit that actually is correct for reasons I hadn't considered is potentially useful to keep me on track.

Comment: open audit post outside of queue and vote in direction _opposite_ to one implied by audit ([Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773))

Comment: ...when possible. Even 10K users can't do anything to counter an answer deleted through review for the wrong reason.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790

Answer (score 15):

Review audits only use posts that are considered unambiguous, i.e. never upvoted for "bad" posts, and never downvoted or close-voted for "good" posts.  If you cast a vote in the opposite direction, the post will not be used for future audits.

(This answer is a duplicate of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773).)

Comment: for the sake of precision, only close and reopen audits are [guaranteed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773 "'No close votes or downvotes, ever (only for close/reopen audits)'") to "die" from single _counter vote_. First Posts, Late Answers (and probably LQ) audits may sometimes need a second vote, see eg [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)

Comment: That's good to know (and thus upvoted), but not sure how it applies to flagged+deleted posts, which was technically the case here. (Especially with my inability to view deleted posts.)